# how to submit query to an asp page using powershell

Tags: html, asp.net, powershell

There is an internal aspx website with one of the page as `http://stackoverflow/answers/Requests.aspx`  This is the page where I submit some data in forms and get the results. 
I am looking for guidelines and workflows as how I can submit the same query/data using powershell.
I am new to interacting websites using powershell but my Powershell skills are advanced.
Or how can I pull the html/xml query from the browser when I submit it on the browser itself to start with?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using a Webforms page.

The short answer is, you really can't do this.

The longer answer: you'll have to adapt this .aspx page. If you do View Source on the page, you'll see some hidden values like `__VIEWSTATE`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, and `__EVENTVALIDATOR`.  These values are rigged up by Webforms to be very hard indeed to guess (that is, to forge). If they're not correct your POST to the page will be rejected. So you can't use Powershell, or curl, or any particular non-browser method to simulat a postback.

To make this work, you have a couple of choices about changing your .aspx.

One:  Add a static [WebMethod] method to the .aspx's code behind page that accepts a post that looks like an AJAX post. Sometimes people call this "adding a web service to the web app."

Two: Add some stuff to the code behind page that accepts POST requests but not in the postback, and interprets the parameters you need to post.